# Updating html using ajax & perl

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, perl

I'm trying to update a div on my webpage using ajax & perl. This is what I have at the moment and it kind of works.

html

```
<h2 id="cpu">--</h2>
```

js/ajax call

```
   $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/cgi-bin/cpu.pl',
      async: true,
      success: function(data) {
        $('#cpu').html(data);
      } 
    });
```

perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# Ref: Calculating CPU Usage from /proc/stat
# (http://colby.id.au/node/39)

use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use utf8;

use List::Util qw(sum);

$| = 1;

my ( $prev_idle, $prev_total ) = qw(0 0);
while () {
    open( STAT, '/proc/stat' ) or die "WTF: $!";
    while (<STAT>) {
        next unless m{^cpu\s+[0-9]+};
        my @cpu = split ' ', $_;
        shift @cpu;

        my $idle  = $cpu[3];
        my $total = sum(@cpu);

        my $diff_idle  = $idle - $prev_idle;
        my $diff_total = $total - $prev_total;
        my $diff_usage = 100 * ( $diff_total - $diff_idle ) / $diff_total;

        $prev_idle  = $idle;
        $prev_total = $total;

        print "Content-type: text/html \n\n";
        printf "%0.2f%%  \r", $diff_usage;
    }
    close STAT;
}
```

This works partially because it does update the the h2 with a percentage but only once. I did have it where it said `sleep 1;` inside the loop and that worked great executing it from the command line but when I used it with ajax and I looked at the network, for cpu.pl it always said status pending and it never changed.

I'm not sure if I'm even going about this the correct way. So any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: seems you have a misunderstanding about how ajax works, it is not an open connection once any data is received

Comment: For continous updates (like does stackoverflow e.g. on votes) you need to use `websockets`, or you need periodocally ask the server via ajax, or read about http-server-push (chunked transfer)....

Comment: you should switch to meteor.js (https://www.meteor.com/) it can instantly update the html without needing to refresh, AND no need to learn a new language, it runs off of JavaScript!  (is that what you want?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I was thinking of ajax the wrong way. Thanks [charlietfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl) for the clarification. I'm still undecided about how I want to go about this. I was originally looking for a *quick and dirty* solution but I'm going to look into both [jm666](https://stackoverflow.com/users/632407/jm666) & [Ian Wise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3781277/ian-wise)'s suggestions.